# Uniquely identify an upload

Tags: javascript, html

I'm uploading files using the following code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
xhr.open("POST", requestUrl, true);
xhr.send(f);
```

Note that I'm attaching a listener to upload progress:

```
function uploadProgress(evt)
{
    // Which upload was it?
}
```

Here's the question, if I have multiple uploads happening at the same time, and they are sharing the same event handler, how can I figure out which upload triggered the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap it as a Control?

```
var uploadProgress = function(uploadObj, event) {
  // Do somthing about uploadObj
}

// Target maybe object or string, whatever you want
var Uploader = function(target) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var handler = uploadProgress.bind(this, target);
  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", handler, false);
  xhr.open("POST", target, true);
  xhr.send(f);
}
```

The .bind will return a new function, when execute the new function, it'll:

1. Use `this` here, the Uploader as its context.
2. Execute uploadProgress and pass `target` as first argument, so the evt given by progess event will be passed to the 2nd param in uploadProgress.

Comment: Not gonna work as-is but might get me going in the right direction. I'll try some stuff tomorrow if nothing better has popped up in the meantime.